# Redshift: how to create datetime field that automatically converts incoming data to 'utc'

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, utc

I want to create a table in redshift that stores incrementally incoming data from the source. The date field in the mysql source is not stored as `UTC`. Is it possible to convert and store the new record as `UTC` upon record creation.

I was thinking doing something like that:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
  my_dt_field datetime without timezone NOT NULL ...)
```

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand -- can you edit it and provide more information? How is the datetime field currently stored in MySQL? Does it have an associated timezone? Please note that SQL clients often convert times into the "local" time on your computer, so it can be hard to tell the format. Can you give an example of the data and how you interpret it?

Comment: hi John.. the field in the mysql table source is actually stored as 'CEST' time and I need to extract the whole table into redshift. redshift itself has 'UTC' as current_timestamp, i was wondering if it would be possible to create the destination table in a way that when the date field of the source flows in ('CEST') it converts automatically to 'UTC'.

Comment: Redshift doesn't actually store as UTC. Rather, it stores dates with a timezone, so it can convert it into any format. The default is UTC, but your SQL client might convert it to a different format. The question is... does the MySQL field have a timezone, or is it simply a datetime without a timezone? You'll need to know that to convert it for Redshift. What does the field look like when exported from MySQL?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein the manual at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Datetime_types.html#r_Datetime_types-timestamptz  disagrees: "*When an input value includes a time zone, Amazon Redshift uses the time zone to convert the value to Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) and stores the UTC value*"

Comment: Ok i see. The field in mysql is actually just a datetime and not specifically stored as ‚cest‘

Comment: Quite possibly. When you load it into Redshift, you'll either load it as a _timestamp with timezone_ or as a plain _timestamp without timezone_. You can then do manipulation to convert into a _timestamp with timezone_, if that's what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redshift provides following options of datatypes available to store dates:

**1.DATE**
Use the DATE data type to store simple calendar dates without time stamps.

**2.TIMESTAMP**
TIMESTAMP is an alias of TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE.

Use the TIMESTAMP data type to store complete timestamp values that include the date and the time of day.

TIMESTAMP columns store values with up to a maximum of 6 digits of precision for fractional seconds.

If you insert a date into a TIMESTAMP column, or a date with a partial time stamp value, the value is implicitly converted into a full time stamp value with default values (00) for missing hours, minutes, and seconds. Time zone values in input strings are ignored.

By default, TIMESTAMP values are Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) in both user tables and Amazon Redshift system tables.

**3.TIMESTAMPTZ**
TIMESTAMPTZ is an alias of TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE.

Use the TIMESTAMPTZ data type to input complete time stamp values that include the date, the time of day, and a time zone. When an input value includes a time zone, Amazon Redshift uses the time zone to convert the value to Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) and stores the UTC value.

To view a list of supported time zone names, execute the following command.
select pg_timezone_names();

**To answer your question declare your column datatype as TIMESTAMP, by default it stores in UTC**

You can also refer AWS document here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Datetime_types.html